# Why can't we take a current carrying bar to determine the magnetic field in Biot savart law?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Our teacher told us that to determine the magnetic field by Biot savart law, we should always consider a wire and not a bar. I don't get the reason for the same. Is it because then we have to take in consideration the thickness of the bar or something?

Comment: Are you sure they didn't mean a bar magnet?

Comment: Aaron Stevens, ya it's clearly mentioned

Comment: Your teacher was right, you've to use Ampere-circuital law for that.

Comment: rv7 can you please explain why can't we use this law?

Comment: Well, they've told to _consider_ a wire, it doesn't imply that we can't use BS law. Just, you've to integrate the stuff ($1D$ expression of $\vec{B}$ around a current-carrying rod) twice to get the $3D$ expression for the $\vec{B}$ around the bar.

Comment: rv7 thank you so much, i got it !